# Proper way to configure Windows 10 firewall for multiple users

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall, netsh

We are deploying a Windows 10 LTSC image to multiple devices. The image configures one admin user and a second non-admin user. The non-admin user is the primary account for day-to-day use of the device. Another part of the configuration is to provide firewall rules for a set of custom applications.

This firewall configuration is currently giving us trouble:

Most of the pre-capture image configuration is driven by Powershell scripts - including the firewall part - while using the admin account.

The script eventually makes a call from within Powershell using Invoke-Expression to 'netsh advfirewall ...' using scripted arguments. One example is shown below:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name='Custom App Rule' enable=Yes profile=Domain,Private,Public dir=In action=Allow protocol=any localip='Any' remoteip='Any' program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Some Company\Bin\CustomApp.exe" edge=deferapp
```

Afterwards, we can check via Windows Defender Firewall editor ('wf.msc') that the entry has been created (output from Export List - Text Tab delimited; tabs changed to comma to save space):

```
Name,Group,Profile,Enabled,Action,Override,Program,Local Address,Remote Address,Protocol,Local Port,Remote Port,Authorized Users,Authorized Computers,Authorized Local Principals,Local User Owner,Application Package  
Custom App Rule,,All,Yes,Allow,No,C:\Program Files (x86)\Some Company\Bin\CustomApp.exe,Any,Any,Any,Any,Any,Any,Any,Any,Any,Any
```

Or reformatted for visibility:

```
Name = Custom App Rule
Group
Profile = All
Enabled = Yes
Action = Allow
Override = No
Program = C:\Program Files (x86)\Some Company\Bin\CustomApp.exe
Local Address = Any
Remote Address = Any
Protocol = Any
Local Port = Any
Remote Port = Any
Authorized Users = Any
Authorized Computers = Any
Authorized Local Principals = Any
Local User Owner = Any
Application Package = Any
```

No error message shows up during the configuration that would imply an issue.

Rebooting the system automatically logs us into the non-admin account (this is by design) and starts our 'customapp.exe'. Which in turn triggers the unexpected firewall prompt:

```
Windows Defender Firewall has blocked some features of this app
Your network administrator can unlock this app for you.
...
Path: C:\program files (x86)\some company\bin\customapp.exe
Network location: Public, private networks
```

And sure enough when checking the Windows Defender Firewall editor, two new 'block' rules have been created for our 'customapp.exe': one for TCP and one for UDP (both with Profile = Public). The only additional difference seems to be that the path in 'Program' is all small caps. Does capitalization in the path matter when trying to match the application to a rule?

Concerns:

- Why is the firewall rule we create specifically for our app seemingly ignored?
- Are we using 'netsh' incorrectly? What would be the correct way?
- Are there any logs that would provide information like: app A asked for network access to X, checking firewall rule 1 ... n, rule y does not apply because of z? (The pfirewall.log seems to only list IP/ports but not application names - at least by default.)

Thank you for taking the time to read this and any advice on this issue.